# Why can't I install 11.10 or 12.04, just on my Windows 7 machines?

Tags: system-installation

I attemted several times to install Ubuntu 11.10,12.04 and 12.10 in my Windows 7 computers with no success. Will work great in my old XP computers. Can you Help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then **edit** your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this carefully https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions
I did on my hp pavillion laptop.